# Apply a font file to ByteArrayOutputStream java

Tags: java, fonts

I am generating a .doc file from an ODT template. The fields are updated with the corresponding fields in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I have a font file `webapp/WEB-INF/arialuni.ttf` which I need to apply to this stream before I generate the DOC file.

```
public byte[] createDOC(ByteArrayOutputStream odtStream, final String fontUrl) {
    // something here to apply the font to odtStream
}
```

The fontUrl is `webapp/WEB-INF/arialuni.ttf`. I was able to apply the font to generate a pdf properly. But that used some classes specifically for PDFs and when I tried using the same to generate doc, it displayed some random characters. Is there a way to apply the font to this OutputStream?

Comment: An ODT file is a **very** complex structured file. It's actually a zip file, I believe with lots of complex content. You can't "apply" a font by looking at the file as a byte stream.

Comment: you mean even if we extract the byte array we will not be able to apply?

Comment: I'd have to say no. In theory, with enough knowledge of the structure of an ODT file, and how to change values and adjust other values and decompress and compress, and so much more, it's possible. But that's so far removed from where you are, that the answer is no.

Comment: ok.. forget about the ODT, but what do we do inorder to apply font to a normal output stream? I will try applying that. If not successful I will leave it.

Comment: What "normal" output stream? A text file doesn't have font information. Binary files without text don't need font information.